# Can descriptors for sockets be converted to File Pointers?

Tags: c, tcp, posix

I got a descriptor for a TCP socket in the following manner :

> `int desc = accept(socket_descriptor, &client_address, &len)`

Now from this descriptor `desc` I want to get a file pointer. Can `fdopen()` be used here ?

The reason I want to get a file pointer is because I am making changes to an existing code that writes data to a local file. Now, I want to extend its functionality so that it can alternatively write to a TCP client. I dont want to rewrite all functions and was thinking of somehow being able to use the existing infrastructure. The existing functions use the file pointer to write to the file. I was wondering if it was possible to make the same function write to a TCP stream without making any changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, [`fdopen()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fopen.3.html) is exactly what you need. Here is what [man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fopen.3.html) is saying about it:

> The fdopen() function associates a stream with the existing file
>   descriptor, fd.  The mode of the stream (one of the values "r", "r+",
>   "w", "w+", "a", "a+") must be compatible with the mode of the file
>   descriptor.  The file position indicator of the new stream is set to
>   that belonging to fd, and the error and end-of-file indicators are
>   cleared.  Modes "w" or "w+" do not cause truncation of the file.  The
>   file descriptor is not dup'ed, and will be closed when the stream
>   created by fdopen() is closed.  The result of applying fdopen() to a
>   shared memory object is undefined.

But use it with caution when applying to socket descriptors. High-level I/O functions use buffering, and may send data differently (i.e. flush whenever `\n` is found in the stream, insert `\r`) etc.

Comment: Most files aren't line buffered, only `stdout`. I'm not sure if there's a way to set a file to be line buffered, but I believe most will be block buffered, which should be a bit more socket friendly.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: The function is `setlinebuf`.  I think `stdout` is only line buffered if it's hooked to a terminal, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - Thank you. And I think you're right about `stdout`.

Comment: I am concerned about the line that says " The mode of the stream must be compatible with the mode of the file  descriptor". Should I use "w" in my  scenario?

Comment: @AnkurVj: Why don't you try it out? I'd recommend starting with "w+" or "bw+" if text and binary files are treated differently (i.e. on Windows).

Comment: I've tried "a+" and "r+". "r+" works only in Mac OS X/iOS, whereas "a+" also works for Linux 3.2.0.

Comment: @ZhangChn: r+ Works for me on Linux.