# Can a descriptor created by socket() be mapped to a memory buffer?

Tags: sockets, mapping, file-descriptor, fdopen

Is there a way to map a descriptor created by socket() to a memory buffer?

The reason why I am looking for this is because I want to make an existing application to read from the memory buffer I created instead of its associated TCP buffer. I shouldn't modify the application, so I want to map a fd returned by the application to a buffer I created.

I found a similar question: 
[Can descriptors for sockets be converted to File Pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780990/can-descriptors-for-sockets-be-converted-to-file-pointers)

But I don't know if fdopen() can be used for my purpose because fdopen() takes only two arguments (fd and mode) and I don't know how to re-associate the fd to a memory I create with malloc().

Comment: How does your application know when there's new data in that `malloc(3)`-ed buffer? There might be a solution, but much depends on your existing interface.

Comment: That is actually a good question. I just assumed that select() of the application (in which I can't make a modification) monitors whether my malloc()ed buffer is ready to be read. But, my assumption may be a big mistake.

Comment: Yeah, figure out how what notifications/callbacks are there. Having that will give you a better idea how to hook into existing app.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to map a descriptor created by socket() to a memory buffer?

No. It doesn't make sense. A mapped file makes sense because of the virtual memory system. A mapped socket doesn't.

> I want to map a fd returned by the application to a buffer I created.

You will have to write code to read from the socket into your buffer.

Comment: I think your answer may not be entirely correct. If Linux, as I should assume, allocates memory to assemble an incoming/outgoing stream of data on a TCP connection, there is in principle nothing wrong with some imaginary system call that maps said memory region as a page in a process page table, thus allowing the process a "zero-copy" socket data read/write operation. This in effect would be akin to a memory-mapped socket receive/transmit buffer.